# Add HTTP Header to all of Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers, django-admin

I'm looking to add an HTTP header to all requests in the Django admin panel. I'm not sure if this could be done with custom views?

I'm using an http header to check later if a user has access to another portion of the website, and the library I'm using does admin scope via HTTP headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add it using a django middleware adding headers to the HttpResponse objects of admin views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be adding the request header for external links since it doesn't seem middleware is invoked then. Are there other options or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: in the middleware you can add headers to responses (outgoing) or request objects (incoming), but you cannot at all add headers to requests (as in http-request, not request object), which the browser makes, because that's not part of your site. Or do you load external links from without django (like urllib)?

Comment: Just a normal html external link right now, but I think it can be possible using urllib?

Comment: You cannot add headers there. The Client can add headers. If you do something serverside, you control the client, but in the webinterface, the user controls the client (browser), not your webapp.